# OpenMPI and rank/core bindings

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

I'm having issues with OpenMPI where different MPI ranks are being repeatably bound to the same CPU cores.

I'm using a server with 32 hardware cores (no hyper-threading), Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and OpenMPI 1.8.4, compiled with Intel compiler 15.0.1.

For instance, I can run my executable with 8 MPI ranks, and get the following rank to core bindings,

```
$ mpirun -n 8 --report-bindings ./executable
[simple:16778] MCW rank 4 bound to socket 0[core 1[hwt 0]]: [./B/./././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 5 bound to socket 1[core 9[hwt 0]]: [./././././././.][./B/./././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 6 bound to socket 2[core 17[hwt 0]]: [./././././././.][./././././././.][./B/./././././.][./././././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 7 bound to socket 3[core 25[hwt 0]]: [./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./B/./././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]: [B/././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 1[core 8[hwt 0]]: [./././././././.][B/././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 2 bound to socket 2[core 16[hwt 0]]: [./././././././.][./././././././.][B/././././././.][./././././././.]
[simple:16778] MCW rank 3 bound to socket 3[core 24[hwt 0]]: [./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][B/././././././.]
```

which works as expected.

The problem is if I run this command a second time (doing a run in different folder), I get exactly the same bindings again. Meaning that out of 32 CPU cores, 8 will have the load twice, while the rest 24 will do nothing.

I am aware of different [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604867/processor-socket-affinity-in-openmpi) of `mpirun` to bind by core, socket, etc. I could, for instance, specify explicitly the cores that should be used with `--cpu-set` argument, or more generally there is the ranking policy,

> --rank-by       Ranking Policy [slot (default) | hwthread | core |
>                            socket | numa | board | node]

What I'm looking for, instead, is a way to automatically distribute the load on the CPU cores that are free, and not reuse the same cores twice. Is there some policy that controls this?

Comment: If you're certain that this behaviour is specific to the machine, then perhaps your system admin can help. Otherwise, instead of calling `mpirun` directly, you might try writing a shell script that detects cores not running your program and calls `mpirun` accordingly for you.

Comment: An instance of `mpirun` has no way of knowing which cores are used by another. That's why things like distributed resource managers (DRMs, also called batch queueing systems) exist. When properly configured, DRMs that understand node topologies can usually provide the necessary information to the MPI library and thus prevent two MPI jobs from binding to the same set of cores.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks for your response, that makes sens. But, suppose we don't want to setup a queuing system (it's just one node, so not really worth it). What about using `--bind-to none` and letting the linux kernel to distribute the load among different CPU cores as it would for normal processes. Is it considered bad practice in HPC?

Comment: That's generally a bad practice in HPC since in some cases binding improves the performance by 30-50% (from my own work experience). Another option would be to write a wrapper script around `mpirun` that keeps track of which cores are used (e.g. in a shared text file) and that generates the proper binding options (or a rankfile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running the executables simultaneously? If not the behavior of your system seems quite logic. 
If you want to run two instances at the same time and make sure they are running on different cores you can try something like this:

```
numactl physcpubind=0-7 mpirun -n 8 --report-bindings ./executable &

numactl pyscpubind=8-31 mpirun -n 24 --report-bindings ./executable
```

Comment: A nice alternative to setting `--cpu-set 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7` etc. explicitly, thanks.